# Onclick not working (Javascript and Dom)

Tags: javascript, dom, onclick

I am trying to get the last function to work, but it isn't. I think it has to do with lank beeing an array?

```
var lank = document.createElement("a"); //Skapa en länk som heter lank
lank.setAttribute("class", "visa");
lank.setAttribute("href", "#");
var lankTN = document.createTextNode("Läs mer"); // Skapa en textnod som heter lankTN
lank.appendChild(lankTN); //Sätt in lankTN i lank

window.onload = function uppstart(){
    var texterna = document.getElementsByClassName("show");
    for (var i = 0; i < texterna.length; i++) {
        texterna[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementsByClassName("post")[i].appendChild(lank.cloneNode(true));
    }
}

function visaText(){
    alert("Hej");
}

lank.onclick = visaText;
```

Comment: what exactly isnt working ?

Comment: Is it just that you have forgotten to append the created anchor to the  body? document.body.appendChild(lank);

Comment: The function isn't starting. There is no alert box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply create the `lank` node inside the for loop and add the onclick there. It would help if we had a fiddle and saw your HTML as well, but I kind of guessed it and I hope this is what you meant: http://jsfiddle.net/yf9Wa/1/.

From the fiddle, would this work for you:

```
window.onload = function uppstart() {
    var texterna = document.getElementsByClassName("show");
    var posterna = document.getElementsByClassName("post");
    for (var i = 0; i < texterna.length; i++) {
        var lank = document.createElement("a"); //Skapa en länk som heter lank
        lank.setAttribute("class", "visa");
        lank.setAttribute("href", "#");
        lank.setAttribute("id", "lank" + i);
        var lankTN = document.createTextNode("Läs mer"); // Skapa en textnod som heter lankTN
        lank.appendChild(lankTN); //Sätt in lankTN i lank
        lank.onclick = function(){
            alert("Hej, jag är: " + this.id);
        };

        texterna[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
        posterna[i].appendChild(lank);
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

If you are worried about performance, don't be.

Comment: ALso, I would highly recommend learning jQuery, makes things like this so much easier and nicer.

Comment: I'm taking a DOM-scripting course. And it is online and teachers not answering any questions&%€##"

Comment: @Delal As expected. Here is your jsfiddle with my logic; check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/S8UEv/1/

Answer (score 0):

`cloneNode` does not seem to copy event handlers. Possibly by design, for security reasons. Attach the event handler to the cloned node, not to `lank`.

```
var cloned = lank.cloneNode(true);
cloned.onclick = visaText;
document.getElementsByClassName("post")[i].appendChild(cloned);
```